# Document.cookie does not work is there alternatives

Tags: javascript, dom, cookies

I tried to retriever a cookie for resolve an dummy exercise. But document.cookie,  in chrome browser, use with url server return an empty value though i know it shoud not.
Did you know a beginning solutions ?

Thanks

`alert(document.cookie)` return nothing as an example.

I tried to print cookie  value  with `document.cookie` but m'y variable Stiller return nothing
`document.cookie.value` return `undefined` though i know there is not regarding the aim of my exercise.

Comment: perhaps you have no cookies accessible to javascript ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯